# Python: loop error in Python Programming for Absolute Beginner "games" module

Tags: python, loops

I'm learning Python and have hit a snag in this code.  I have even pulled down the author's code and it has the same problem. :(

After importing the "random" module and the "games" module, which includes the "ask_number()" function and the class definition for a "Player," we have:

```
again = None
while again != "n":
    players = []
    num = games.ask_number(question = "How many players? (2-5): ", low = 2, high = 5)
    for i in range(num):
        name = input("Player name: ")
        score = random.randrange(100) + 1
        player = games.Player(name, score)
        players.append(player)
```

The "ask_number()" function looks like this:

```
def ask_number(question, low, high):
    """Ask for a number within a range."""
    response = None
    while response not in range(low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response
```

When the program is run, however, the question "How many players? (2-5):" appears ad infinitum, regardless of what number is input as a response.  Clearly it seems some kind of erroneous loop has been set up, but I can't figure out what it is for the life of me (that's why I'm an "absolute beginner," haha!).

Thanks in advance for returning my sanity to me! :)

EDITED:
Since I thought the problem was merely with the syntax of the ask_number() function, I didn't want to append a lot of extraneous code.  Learned that lesson! :)  This is the full loop, so it does seem that again has a changeable value.  (Note that the "ask_yes_no()" function is also in the "games" module.)

```
again = None
while again != "n":
    players = []
    num = games.ask_number(question = "How many players? (2-5): ", low = 2, high = 5)
    for i in range(num):
        name = input("Player name: ")
        score = random.randrange(100) + 1
        player = games.Player(name, score)
        players.append(player)
    print("\nHere are the game results:")
    for player in players:
        print(player)
    again = games.ask_yes_no("\nDo you want to play again? (y/n): ")
```

Comment: If you are using Python 2.7, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`

Comment: you never set the variable again equal to "n". this results in your while loop iterating on into infinity and the "how many players" prompt to keep reappearing

Comment: Also note that 5 isn't actually in `range(2, 5)`, as that's only 2-4.

Comment: That looks like it should work. Can you confirm that you tried to enter `2`, `3`, or `4` as the number of players and that you never see the "Player name: " prompt?

Comment: Confirmed, Anym.  It just cycles endlessly on the how many players question, despite entering 2, 3, or 4 as the answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me regain my sanity.  Your assurances that the code should work emboldened me to find a typo (naturally...).  Surprising that the book incorrectly used 2-5 when "5" isn't in the range! (I was definitely a bit confused about that.)

Answer (score 2):

you are saying

```
while again != "n":
```

but you never set again! Because again never equals 'n' it never exits the loop

Answer (score 0):

You are never changing the value of `again`. In order to fix this you could add this

```
again = raw_input("Play again?: ")
```

at the end of the `while` loop.